# Android - Synchronization from server side mysql to client side sqlite

Tags: android, xmpp, google-cloud-messaging, alarm

My android app need to perform a synchronization from server side mysql to client side sqlite.
When some data is changed or inserted on server, it must be synchronized with Sqlite on users devices. My backend is java web application with jersey REST.
Whats the best approach ? Scheduling repeating alarms,  GCM with HTTP Connection Server or GCM with XMPP Connection Server ?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best approach is sync adapter with content provider as entrance to sqlite db..scheudling of sync can be periodic ,GCM or other..you can find all details and sample code in this book http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Enterprise-Android-Programming-Android-Database-Applications-for-the-Enterprise.productCd-1118183495.html and projects and source code from book at https://github.com/wileyenterpriseandroid/Examples also on google documentation for sync adapter,content provider etc..

Comment: Also when you got the time look at this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE , you feel get the feeling of how Google imagine REST apps arhitecture